# how to iterate articles with images inside with vue

Tags: vue.js

I have to iterate some articles which contain images inside. The thing is that it doesn't work what I'm doing.

I have tried an v-for inside the article ad then, binding the src like this:

```
<section class="articulos b-flex b-flex-wrap b-flex-center b-flex-center-horizontal">

        <article v-for="imagen in imagenes">

            <figure class="contenedor-articulo">

                    <img v-bind:src="'../assets/img/' + imagen.url" /> 

                        <figcaption>

                            <h3>Ensaladilla Rusa</h3>

                            <p>+ 0,50 €</p>

                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>

                        </figcaption>

            </figure>

        </article>





    </section>
```

the script of the component is like this:

```
<script>

    export default {
  name: 'Articulos',
  data() {

      return {
           imagenes: [

                {url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg"},
                {url:"apeteat_2017__ensaladilla_rusa.jpg"},
                {url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg"},
                {url:"apeteat_2019_wrapcesar.jpg"},
                {url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg"},  
                {url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg"}

          ]

      }
  }

}
</script>
```

I have this error message:

```
message: error: Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives (vue/require-v-for-key) at src/components/Articulos.vue:4:9:
  2 | 
  3 | <section class="articulos b-flex b-flex-wrap b-flex-center b-flex-center-horizontal">
> 4 |         <article v-for="imagen in imagenes">
    |         ^
  5 | 
  6 |             <figure class="contenedor-articulo">
```

the image is not displaying. Tha image url is so:
src="../assets/img/apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg", before iterating thwy were displaying perfectly.

Comment: You can avoid syntax errors like this by installing [eslint](https://eslint.org/) along with [eslint-plugin-vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add unique `key` when use `v-for`.

```
<article
 v-for="(imagen, index) in imagenes"
 :key="index"
>
```

Using index as key is not recommended. Please add unique key or id in each image object like below.

```
[
  { 
    id: 1,
    url:"2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg"
  },
  ...
]
...

<article
 v-for="imagen in imagenes"
 :key="imagen.id"
>
```

Comment: In production it won't work. Because of Webpack, to path the images /assets, you will need to use <img  :src="require(`@/assets/${imagen.imagenes}`)" />

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with your **imagenes** array.

Instead of this (array with one object with duplicated keys):

```
imagenes: [{

                url:"2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg",
                url:"2017__ensaladilla_rusa.jpg",
                url:"2018_nigirimix.jpg",
                url:"2019_wrapcesar.jpg",
                url:"2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg",  
                url:"2018_nigirimix.jpg"

          }]
```

It most likely should be this (array of objects):

```
imagenes: [
  { url:"2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg" },
  { url:"2017__ensaladilla_rusa.jpg" },
  { url:"2018_nigirimix.jpg" },
  { url:"2019_wrapcesar.jpg" },
  { url:"2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg" },
  { url:"2018_nigirimix.jpg" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it iterates perfectly but the images are not displaying. I wrote the error  message...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a '/' in your path binding like this : `v-bind:src="'../assets/img/apeteat_/' + imagen.url"`

Also, rewrite your `imagenes` array to be like this (they key 'url' is duplicated):

```js
imagenes: [
    {url: //img name },
    {url: //img name }
    //etc
]
```

Comment: Ichanged it and it iterates, just fine. But the images are still not being displayed.

Comment: then the problem now is more likely to be with the "../assets/img/" part of the path, maybe try ```/assets/img/``` ? The point is that you need to check that your path is actually referencing the right directory.

Comment: Tha image url is so: src="../assets/img/apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg", before iterating thwy were displaying perfectly.

Comment: if ```apeteat_``` is actually part of your image names and not a directory name then you shouldn't add the '/' and revert back to ```v-bind:src="'../assets/img/apeteat_' + imagen.url"``` (it wasn't clear in your original post) .... can you show your directory structure?

Comment: and if there is any errors showing on your browser console show it here.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<article v-for="imagen in imagenes" :key="imagen.id">
  <img  :src="require(`@/assets/${imagen.imagenes}`)" /> 
  ...
</article>
```

In JS

```
imagenes: [
      {id:1, url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg"},
      {id:2, url:"apeteat_2017__ensaladilla_rusa.jpg"},
      {id:3, url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg"},
      {id:4, url:"apeteat_2019_wrapcesar.jpg"},
      {id:5, url:"apeteat_2019_ensaladaquinoachicken.jpg"},  
      {id:6, url:"apeteat_2018_nigirimix.jpg"}
]
```